# Bing Translate , C# code

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, bing-api

Am using Bing Translate to translate a few records in my table. I use the Translate method of the API to do the translation. However since my records are in multiple languages I want the Bing Translator to pick up those records , auto-detect the language and then translate. But this doesn't seem to be working.I have used the following code to call the translate method:

```
translatedText = client.Translate("", sourceText,"" ,"en", "text/plain", "general");
```

Comment: Your debugger doesn't know how to say 'Invalid from value'. Something else must be saying it. Exactly how does "it" say this?

Comment: [] Error: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'from' must be a valid language
Parameter name: from : ID=3925.V2_Soap.Translate.443C822F

Comment: This is the Bing service complaining that the `from` parameter must be a valid language parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the flavors of [Detect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512396.aspx) (maybe `DetectArray`) first and than call `Translate` as it requires language to translate from.

Comment: That worked like a charm :) Thanks a ton Alexei Levenkov! You are a star!